# JQUERY - Suma de INPUTS dinamicos con CONDICIONAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Hola compañeros de StackOverFlow,

Me encuentro con el siguiente duda:

Como puedo sumar todos los `input` con `name` **VN_TOTAL[]** cuando el input con name **VN_GRABIVA[]** de la misma fila de la tabla este vació o sea igual a cero.

Dicho total lo necesito guardar en el `input` con ID **siniva**.

de la misma forma necesito sumar todos los `input` con `name` **VN_TOTAL[]** cuando el input con name **VN_GRABIVA[]** de la misma fila de la tabla tenga algun valor mayor a cero.

Esta suma la necesito en el input con ID **coniva**.

En la siguiente imagen muestro el resultado que estoy buscando como ejemplo:

https://i.ibb.co/CsbfqZ1/zrmrf.jpg

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tr = 2;
    $('#addrowdte').on("click", function() {
        $(".details-dte").append('<tr id="'+tr+'"> <td><button onclick="remove_tr('+tr+')" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button> </td> <td> <input onkeyup="subtotal('+tr+');" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles cantidad'+tr+'" name="VN_CANTIDA[]" value=""> </td> <td> <div class="input-group"> <input style="min-width: 100px;" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="required" id="ADD_CODIGO'+tr+'" name="VN_CODPRO[]" value=""> <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-search-product" onclick="getrowid('+tr+');" class="input-group-addon input-sm"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a> </div> </td> <td> <input id="ADD_DETALLE'+tr+'" type="text" class="input-sm" name="VN_DETALLE[]" value=""> </td> <td> <input id="ADD_VALUNI'+tr+'" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles precio'+tr+'" name="VN_VALUNI[]" value=""> </td> <td> <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles subtotal'+tr+'" name="VN_PARCIAL[]" value=""> </td> <td> <input onkeyup="get_total('+tr+');" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles descuento'+tr+'" name="VN_TASADES[]" placeholder="00,00"> </td> <td> <input id="ADD_VALIVA'+tr+'" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles iva'+tr+'" name="VN_GRABIVA[]" value=""> </td> <td> <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles total'+tr+'" name="VN_TOTAL[]" value=""> </td> </tr>');
        tr++;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead class="bg-info text-white">
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><a id="addrowdte" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
            </td>
            <th>CANTIDAD</th>
            <th>CODIGO</th>
            <th>NOMBRE</th>
            <th>PRECIO</th>
            <th>SUB TOTAL</th>
            <th>DCTO %</th>
            <th>IVA %</th>
            <th>TOTAL</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="details-dte">
        <tr id="1">
            <td>
                <button onclick="remove_tr(1)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input onkeyup="subtotal(1);" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles cantidad1" name="VN_CANTIDA[]" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input style="min-width: 100px;" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="required" id="ADD_CODIGO1" name="VN_CODPRO[]" value="">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-search-product" onclick="getrowid(1);" class="input-group-addon input-sm"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="ADD_DETALLE1" type="text" class="input-sm" name="VN_DETALLE[]" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="ADD_VALUNI1" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles precio1" name="VN_VALUNI[]" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles subtotal1" name="VN_PARCIAL[]" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input onkeyup="get_total(1);" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles descuento1" name="VN_TASADES[]" placeholder="00,00">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="ADD_VALIVA1" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles iva1" name="VN_GRABIVA[]" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles total1" name="VN_TOTAL[]" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    function remove_tr(id) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (id != 1) {
            $('#' + id).remove();
        }
    }

    function subtotal(idrow) {
        var rowid = idrow;
        var cantidad, precio, total, iva;
        if ($('.cantidad' + rowid).val().length > 0) {
            cantidad = parseFloat($('.cantidad' + rowid).val());
        } else {
            cantidad = 0;
        }
        if ($('.precio' + rowid).val().length > 0) {
            precio = parseFloat($('.precio' + rowid).val());
        } else {
            precio = 0;
        }
        total = (precio * cantidad);
        $('.subtotal' + rowid).val(total);

        if ($('.iva' + rowid).val().length > 0) {
            iva = parseFloat($('.iva' + rowid).val());
            iva = (total * iva / 100);
            total = (total + iva);
        }

        $('.total' + rowid).val(total);
    };

    function get_total(idrow) {
        var rowid = idrow;
        var subtotal, descuento, total, iva;
        subtotal = parseFloat($('.subtotal' + rowid).val());
        if ($('.descuento' + rowid).val().length <= 0) {
            descuento = 0;
        } else {
            descuento = parseFloat($('.descuento' + rowid).val());
        }
        total = (subtotal * descuento / 100);
        total = (subtotal - total);
        if ($('.iva' + rowid).val().length > 0) {
            iva = parseFloat($('.iva' + rowid).val());
            iva = (total * iva / 100);
            total = (total + iva);
        }
        $('.total' + rowid).val(total);

    }
</script><br>
<span>Total sin iva:</span>
<input type="text" id="siniva" value="">
<br><br>
<span>Total con iva:</span>
<input type="text" id="coniva" value="">
```

Cualquier duda o novedad estaré muy pendiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre el código que tienes se puede hacer recorriendo cada fila (tr) y buscando si el campo iva está vacío, en función de este campo sumamos a la cantidad de precios con iva o a la cantidad de precios sin iva. Añado un ejemplo sencillos en que la función se ejecuta al hacer click en 'calcular totales', una vez rellenos el campo iva y total de las filas. Espero que te sirva.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tr = 2;
    $('#addrowdte').on("click", function() {
        $(".details-dte").append('<tr id="'+tr+'"> <td><button onclick="remove_tr('+tr+')" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button> </td> <td> <input onkeyup="subtotal('+tr+');" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles cantidad'+tr+'" name="VN_CANTIDA[]" value=""> </td> <td> <div class="input-group"> <input style="min-width: 100px;" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="required" id="ADD_CODIGO'+tr+'" name="VN_CODPRO[]" value=""> <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-search-product" onclick="getrowid('+tr+');" class="input-group-addon input-sm"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a> </div> </td> <td> <input id="ADD_DETALLE'+tr+'" type="text" class="input-sm" name="VN_DETALLE[]" value=""> </td> <td> <input id="ADD_VALUNI'+tr+'" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles precio'+tr+'" name="VN_VALUNI[]" value=""> </td> <td> <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles subtotal'+tr+'" name="VN_PARCIAL[]" value=""> </td> <td> <input onkeyup="get_total('+tr+');" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles descuento'+tr+'" name="VN_TASADES[]" placeholder="00,00"> </td> <td> <input id="ADD_VALIVA'+tr+'" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles iva'+tr+'" name="VN_GRABIVA[]" value=""> </td> <td> <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles total'+tr+'" name="VN_TOTAL[]" value=""> </td> </tr>');
        tr++;
    });
});


function CalcularTotales() {
var totalconiva = 0;
var totalsiniva = 0;
  $(".details-dte").find("tr").each(function(){
    var filaconiva = 0;
    $(this).find("input:text").each(function(){
      if ($(this).attr("name")=="VN_GRABIVA[]") {
        if ($(this).val()!="" && $(this).val()!="0") {
           filaconiva = 1; 
        }
      }
      if ($(this).attr("name")=="VN_TOTAL[]") {
        //alert($(this).val());
        if (filaconiva==1) { 
          totalconiva = totalconiva + parseInt($(this).val());
        } else { 
          totalsiniva = totalsiniva + parseInt($(this).val());
        }
      }
    });
  });

  $("#siniva").val(totalsiniva);
  $("#coniva").val(totalconiva);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead class="bg-info text-white">
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><a id="addrowdte" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
            </td>
            <th>CANTIDAD</th>
            <th>CODIGO</th>
            <th>NOMBRE</th>
            <th>PRECIO</th>
            <th>SUB TOTAL</th>
            <th>DCTO %</th>
            <th>IVA %</th>
            <th>TOTAL</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="details-dte">
        <tr id="1">
            <td>
                <button onclick="remove_tr(1)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input onkeyup="subtotal(1);" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles cantidad1" name="VN_CANTIDA[]" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input style="min-width: 100px;" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="required" id="ADD_CODIGO1" name="VN_CODPRO[]" value="">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-search-product" onclick="getrowid(1);" class="input-group-addon input-sm"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="ADD_DETALLE1" type="text" class="input-sm" name="VN_DETALLE[]" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="ADD_VALUNI1" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles precio1" name="VN_VALUNI[]" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles subtotal1" name="VN_PARCIAL[]" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input onkeyup="get_total(1);" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles descuento1" name="VN_TASADES[]" placeholder="00,00">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="ADD_VALIVA1" type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles iva1" name="VN_GRABIVA[]" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles total1" name="VN_TOTAL[]" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    function remove_tr(id) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (id != 1) {
            $('#' + id).remove();
        }
    }

    function subtotal(idrow) {
        var rowid = idrow;
        var cantidad, precio, total, iva;
        if ($('.cantidad' + rowid).val().length > 0) {
            cantidad = parseFloat($('.cantidad' + rowid).val());
        } else {
            cantidad = 0;
        }
        if ($('.precio' + rowid).val().length > 0) {
            precio = parseFloat($('.precio' + rowid).val());
        } else {
            precio = 0;
        }
        total = (precio * cantidad);
        $('.subtotal' + rowid).val(total);

        if ($('.iva' + rowid).val().length > 0) {
            iva = parseFloat($('.iva' + rowid).val());
            iva = (total * iva / 100);
            total = (total + iva);
        }

        $('.total' + rowid).val(total);
    };

    function get_total(idrow) {
        var rowid = idrow;
        var subtotal, descuento, total, iva;
        subtotal = parseFloat($('.subtotal' + rowid).val());
        if ($('.descuento' + rowid).val().length <= 0) {
            descuento = 0;
        } else {
            descuento = parseFloat($('.descuento' + rowid).val());
        }
        total = (subtotal * descuento / 100);
        total = (subtotal - total);
        if ($('.iva' + rowid).val().length > 0) {
            iva = parseFloat($('.iva' + rowid).val());
            iva = (total * iva / 100);
            total = (total + iva);
        }
        $('.total' + rowid).val(total);

    }
</script><br>
<span>Total sin iva:</span>
<input type="text" id="siniva" value="">
<br><br>
<span>Total con iva:</span>
<input type="text" id="coniva" value="">
<br><br>
<div onclick="CalcularTotales()">Calcular Totales</div>
```

Comment: Hola, una consulta adicional si quisiera formatear esos totales en separador de miles con dos decimales, como podria hacerlo? necesito algo como esto 1.800,50  punto para miles y coma para decimales, muchas gracias.

Comment: Te paso un enlace dónde puedes ver cómo hacerlo https://blog.abelotech.com/posts/number-currency-formatting-javascript/.

Answer (score 2):

Una solución es que cada vez que varíes las cantidades, actualices una propiedad en el input de total correspondiente a la fila que estás modificando, para que cuando recorras todos los inputs para calcular el monto total, puedas discernir entre sumar la cantidad al campo con IVA o al campo sin IVA.

Algo así:

```
// Cada vez que se modifique el campo de IVA
$totalCorrespondiente.data({
    tieneIVA: !!valordeIva,
    total: valordeTotal
});
```

Después cuando necesites calcular los totales puedes recorrer todos los inputs de totales para sumar sus valores tomando en cuenta el flag `tieneIVA`:

```
var $totales = $tableDetails.find('tr input[name="VN_TOTAL[]"]').toArray();
var totales = $totales.reduce(function (obj, input) {
    var $input = $(input);
    if ($input.data('tieneIVA')) {
        obj.coniva += $input.data('total');
    } else {
        obj.siniva += $input.data('total');
    }
    return obj;
}, {coniva: 0, siniva: 0});

$totalSinIVA.val(totales.siniva);
$totalConIVA.val(totales.coniva);
```

Aquí te dejo tu código con este cambio:

> He realizado algunas variaciones al código que creo te podrían servir, pero no están relacionadas con tu pregunta, así que te las dejo al final del snippet. Dichas recomendaciones están basadas en mi experiencia y mi opinión personal, toma de ellas lo que estimes conveniente.

```js
var template = $('#tableRow').html();
var tr = 1;
var $tableDetails = $('.details-dte');
var $totalSinIVA = $('#siniva');
var $totalConIVA = $('#coniva');

// Función para añadir una fila variando el HTML del template
function addRow(index) {
  $tableDetails.append(template.replace(/\{\{tr-index\}\}/g, index));
}

// Añadir la primera fila por defecto
addRow(++tr);

// Devolver el valor de un input o 0 si no tiene valor
function parseValue() {
  return isNaN(this.val()) || +this.val() === 0 ? 0 : +this.val();
}

$('#addrowdte').on('click', function() {
  addRow(++tr);
});

// Eliminar fila 
$tableDetails.on('click', 'tr button', function () {
  var $button = $(this);
  $button.closest('tr').remove();
});

// Calcular los totales de todas las filas
function calcularTotales () {
  var $totales = $tableDetails.find('tr input[name="VN_TOTAL[]"]').toArray();
  var totales = $totales.reduce(function (obj, input) {
    var $input = $(input);
    if ($input.data('tieneIVA')) {
      obj.coniva += ($input.data('total') || 0);
    } else {
      obj.siniva += ($input.data('total') || 0);
    }
    return obj;
  }, {coniva: 0, siniva: 0});
  $totalSinIVA.val(totales.siniva);
  $totalConIVA.val(totales.coniva);
}

var inputs = ['VN_CANTIDA[]', 'VN_VALUNI[]', 'VN_TASADES[]', 'VN_GRABIVA[]'].map(function (iname) {
  return 'tr input[name="' + iname + '"]';
});

$tableDetails.on('keyup', inputs.join(','), function () {
  var $input = $(this);
  var $row = $input.closest('tr');
  var $quantity = $row.find('input[name="VN_CANTIDA[]"]');
  var $precio = $row.find('input[name="VN_VALUNI[]"]');
  var $descuento = $row.find('input[name="VN_TASADES[]"]');
  var $iva = $row.find('input[name="VN_GRABIVA[]"]');
  var $subtotal = $row.find('input[name="VN_PARCIAL[]"]'); 
  var $total = $row.find('input[name="VN_TOTAL[]"]');
  
  var cantidad = parseValue.call($quantity);
  var precio = parseValue.call($precio);
  var descuento = parseValue.call($descuento);
  var iva = parseValue.call($iva);
  var subtotal = cantidad * precio;
  var totalConDescuento = subtotal - subtotal * (descuento / 100);
  var total = totalConDescuento + totalConDescuento * (iva / 100);
  
  // Guardar el total y si tiene o no iva en el campo VN_TOTAL[]  
  $total.data({
    total: total,
    tieneIVA: !!iva
  });
  
  // Aplicar cálculos
  $subtotal.val(subtotal);
  $total.val(total); 
  
  // Calcular los totales
  calcularTotales();
  
});
```

```css
.details-dte tr:nth-child(1) button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <thead class="bg-info text-white">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><a id="addrowdte" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
      </td>
      <th>CANTIDAD</th>
      <th>CODIGO</th>
      <th>NOMBRE</th>
      <th>PRECIO</th>
      <th>SUB TOTAL</th>
      <th>DCTO %</th>
      <th>IVA %</th>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="details-dte">
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<span>Total sin iva:</span>
<input type="text" id="siniva" value="">
<br><br>
<span>Total con iva:</span>
<input type="text" id="coniva" value="">

<template id="tableRow">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles cantidad-{{tr-index}}" name="VN_CANTIDA[]" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input style="min-width: 100px;" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" required="required" name="VN_CODPRO[]" value="">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-search-product" class="input-group-addon input-sm">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input-sm" name="VN_DETALLE[]" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles precio-{{tr-index}}" name="VN_VALUNI[]" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles subtotal-{{tr-index}}" name="VN_PARCIAL[]" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles descuento-{{tr-index}}" name="VN_TASADES[]" placeholder="00,00">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles iva-{{tr-index}}" name="VN_GRABIVA[]" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input-sm separ-miles total-{{tr-index}}" name="VN_TOTAL[]" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

**Consejos que te pueden servir y que he incluido en el código, así que puedes ver la implementación de estos allí:**

Intenta siempre que puedas, separar el código `HTML` del código `JavaScript` y viceversa (a no ser que estés trabajando con `JSX`). Si quieres usar un template determinado que vas a utilizar de manera contínua en el código, una técnica que puedes utilizar es situar el `HTML` correspondiente a dicho template dentro de una etiqueta [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/template) o incluso dentro de una etiqueta `script` de tipo `template`. Esto hará que el código del template sea más fácil de leer y modificar. Si te hace falta que ciertas variables en el template sean dinámicas, podrías situar *placeholders* para remplazarlos con parámetros con un simple [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace).

En la misma línea de esta recomendación, intenta añadir los eventos `JavaScript`, desde el código `JavaScript` en vez de directo en el `HTML`. En vez de añadir un evento por cada botón o input de cada fila (que van aumentando a medida que aumentan las filas), puedes, mediante [delegación de eventos](https://medium.com/@osmancea/delegaci%C3%B3n-de-eventos-del-dom-con-javascript-d28131d43686) añadir dicho evento solo una vez y funcionará sin importar la cantidad de filas que tenga la tabla.

Intenta siempre que puedas hacer *caching* en variables de los objetos `jQuery` si estos objetos los vas a usar de manera contínua en el código. Cada vez que llamas a `$("selector")`, `jQuery` necesita recorrer el `DOM` para buscar y seleccionar dicho elemento, por lo que esto tiene un coste. Solo usa los selectores dentro de la lógica del código si los elementos que estás intentando seleccionar son dinámicos y pueden cambiar, pero si los elementos son fijos, asígnalos a variables y usa esas variables en su lugar, así la búsqueda del elemento y este coste de procesamiento se realiza solo una vez.

Si vas a repetir un código más de una vez, debes plantearte si no es mejor usar una función para realizar la funcionalidad de esa lógica. En tu código tienes múltiples lugares en los que chequeas si el valor de un `input` tiene una longitud mayor que `0` para dependiendo de esto aplicarle un `parseFloat`. Puedes crear una pequeña función para esto y aplicarla cada vez que quieras hacerlo (tu código será más sencillo de leer y de escalar).

Intenta no tener en la interfaz elementos que al interactuar con ellos ignoras la interacción del usuario con `JavaScript`, esto es confuso para el usuario porque su interacción no es respetada. En su lugar puedes mediante `CSS` cambiar la apariencia de los elementos con los que no se puede interactuar. En el código oculté el ícono de borrar de la primera fila, esto no es ideal, lo ideal sería no mostrar el ícono si hay solo una fila o mostrarlos si hay más de una (el usuario debe poder borrar la primera fila si lo desea), pero aunque no es ideal, es mejor solución que mostrar el ícono de borrar e ignorarlo con `JavaScript` si se se trata de la primera fila.

Comment: Tanto tu codigo como tu explicación es bastante util.

Comment: Me alegro que te sirva de ayuda @ByGroxD, un saludo.

Comment: Donde encuentro un curso de JS de ese nivel?

Comment: Hola @ByGroxD, estas cosas las puedes encontrar en cursos en los que traten el tema de buenas prácticas, pero la verdad no te sabría decir de alguno en este momento, pero creo que si te pasas por [el chat de la comunidad](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) algún compañero te puede recomendar alguno bueno.