# ¿Cómo puedo concatenar condicionales y bucles? Usando HTML y JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero realizar una tabla donde se muestre cierta información dependiendo de un condicional, pero para realizarla necesito concatenar dicha tabla con un condicional y un bucle (ya que es la manera que se me ocurrió, no sé si habrá otra manera).

> *NOTA*: En el siguiente articulo [Concatenating strings with `if` statements in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344309/concatenating-strings-with-if-statements-in-javascript) muestran una manera con operador ternario pero no es lo que busco.

**Javascript:**

```
var opcion = ['BBVA', 'SANTANDER', 'BANCO PLAZA', 'BANK OF AMERICA']

var table = $("#table")

table.append("<table id='mi_tabla' class='table table-sm table-striped table-bordered' style='width:100%'></table>")

var mi_tabla = $("mi_tabla")

mi_tabla
    .append("<thead>" + 
                "<tr>" +
                    "<th scope='col'>Banco</th>" +
                    "<th scope='col'>Saldo</th>" +
                    "<th scope='col'>PM%EST</th>" +
                    "<th scope='col'>PM%SIS</th>" +
                "</tr>" +
            "</thead>" +
            "<tbody>" +
                "<tr>" +
                    //Aqui no se como podria concatenarlo
                    for(let i = 0; i < opcion.length; ++i)
                    {
                        if(opcion[i] == 'Santander')
                        {
                            "<td class='bg-success'>Santander</td>" +
                            "<td>20000</td>" + 
                            "<td>500,00</td>" +
                            "<td>100</td>" +
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            "<td class='bg-success'>" + opcion[i] + "</td>" +
                            "<td>20000</td>" + 
                            "<td>500,00</td>" +
                            "<td>100</td>" +
                        }
                    }

                "</tr>" +

            "</tbody>"
    )
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="col-12 my-4" id="table"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No entiendo por qué dices que lo que buscas no es un operador ternario. Si un operador ternario resuelve tu problema debería servirte, de lo contrario deberías explicar por qué no lo deseas utilizar.

Antes de brindarte una posible solución, pásate por las recomendaciones que dejé en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/294795/jquery-suma-de-inputs-dinamicos-con-condicional/296090#296090), creo que podrían servirte de ayuda.

Ahora, volviendo a tu código. No debes escribir código `HTML` usando `jQuery`, si la tabla tiene elementos que son fijos y no varían, sitúa estos elementos directamente en el código `HTML`. Haciéndolo de la manera que lo estás haciendo, no solo complicas tu código y lo haces más difícil de leer, escalar y mantener, sino que te creas otros problemas como el que estás presentando.

En la siguiente solución he usado uno de los consejos que dejé en la respuesta enlazada. Usar un *template* para las filas te ayudará a mantener separado el código `JavaScript` y `HTML`, aparte de ser mucho más fácil de leer y editar. Usando esta técnica, puedes simplemente hacer un [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) del `array` `opcion` para crear un `array` de filas, las cuales, dependiendo de una condición ternaria, devolverán el *template* de cada fila remplazando la parte correspondiente a la primera columna con una cadena u otra.

Como puedes ver, usando esta solución no solo eliminas la complicación de concatenar las cadenas con un ciclo y una condición intermedia sino que el código es mucho más sencillo de leer y comprender:

```js
var opcion = ['BBVA', 'SANTANDER', 'BANCO PLAZA', 'BANK OF AMERICA'];

var $body = $("#mi_tabla tbody");
var template = $("#row_template").html();

var rows = opcion.map(function (op) {
    return template.replace("{{banco}}", op === "SANTANDER" ? "Santander" : op);
});

$body.append(rows);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 my-4" id="table">
  <table id='mi_tabla' class='table table-sm table-striped table-bordered' style='width:100%'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope='col'>Banco</th>
      <th scope='col'>Saldo</th>
      <th scope='col'>PM%EST</th>
      <th scope='col'>PM%SIS</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<template id="row_template">
  <tr>
    <td class='bg-success'>{{banco}}</td>
    <td>20000</td>
    <td>500,00</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

**Edición:** Leyendo tu comentario, parece que tus datos son más complejos que un simple `array` (el código está pensado para el caso específico que habías situado en la pregunta). Si necesitas devolver un template diferente para cada fila dependiendo de condiciones situadas en cada una de sus celdas, aquí te dejo otro ejemplo usando el mismo método con una estructura más compleja. Mediante condiciones se devuelven diferentes valores por celdas (en el ejemplo solo realizo las condiciones en las celdas pertenecientes a dos columnas):

```js
var datos = [
  { banco: "BBVA", saldo:  "20000", pmest: "500,00", pmsis: "100"},
  { banco: "SANTANDER", saldo:  "10000", pmest: "400,00", pmsis: "200" },
  { banco: "BANCO PLAZA", saldo:  "50000", pmest: "300,00", pmsis: "700" },
  { banco: "BANK OF AMERICA", saldo:  "40000", pmest: "100,00", pmsis: "200" }
];

var $body = $("#mi_tabla tbody");
var template = $("#row_template").html();

var filas = datos.map(function (fila) {
    return template.replace(/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/g, function (m, p) {
      switch (p) {
        case "banco":
          return fila[p] === "SANTANDER" ? "Santander" : fila[p];
        case "saldo":
          return +fila[p] > 10000 ? "<del>" + fila[p] + "</del>" : fila[p];
        default:
          return fila[p];
      }
    });
});

$body.append(filas);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 my-4" id="table">
  <table id='mi_tabla' class='table table-sm table-striped table-bordered' style='width:100%'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope='col'>Banco</th>
      <th scope='col'>Saldo</th>
      <th scope='col'>PM%EST</th>
      <th scope='col'>PM%SIS</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<template id="row_template">
  <tr>
    <td class='bg-success'>{{banco}}</td>
    <td>{{saldo}}</td>
    <td>{{pmest}}</td>
    <td>{{pmsis}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Primero que nada gracias por responder, me has dado buenas ideas y leeré el enlace que dejaste para poder orientarme mejor. Lo del operador ternario sucede que por lo menos en el ejemplo que doy, es muy sencillo, ya que en realidad para la condición manipulo un objeto literal con otros objetos literales dentro de él y no un array como muestro en el ejemplo, para no realizar la pregunta muy compleja lo coloque de esa manera

Comment: @Alvarez, de nada, ¡espero que te sirva de ayuda!

Answer (score 3):

Acomode tu código de la siguiente manera, no es necesario concatenar cada etiqueta `tr`, `td` con [*template strings*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) puedes acomodarlo como si fuera formato HTML, creas una variable vacía y vas concatenando, podrías dejar en HTMl el cuerpo de tu `table` hasta el `tbody` y lo demás crearlo y agregarlo con jQuery, espero te sirva.

```js
var opcion = ['BBVA', 'SANTANDER', 'BANCO PLAZA', 'BANK OF AMERICA']

  var table = $("#table");

  //table.append("<table id='mi_tabla' class='table table-sm table-striped table-bordered' //style='width:100%'></table>")

  //var mi_tabla = $("mi_tabla")

let contenidoTabla = '';

contenidoTabla += `

<table id='mi_tabla' class='table table-sm table-striped table-bordered' style='width:100%'>

              <thead>  
                        <tr> 
                            <th scope='col'>Banco</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Saldo</th>
                            <th scope='col'>PM%EST</th>
                            <th scope='col'>PM%SIS</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        `;
                          //Aqui no se como podria concatenarlo
                          for(let i = 0; i < opcion.length; ++i)
                          {
                            if(opcion[i] === 'SANTANDER')
                            {
                            contenidoTabla += `
                            </tr>
                              <td class='bg-success'>Santander</td>
                               <td>20000</td> 
                               <td>500,00</td>
                               <td>100</td>
                               </tr>
                               `;
                               
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            contenidoTabla += `<tr>
                              <td class='bg-success'>${opcion[i]}</td>
                              <td>20000</td> 
                              <td>500,00</td>
                              <td>100</td>
                              </tr>`
                              
                            }
                          }

                        contenidoTabla += `

                    </tbody>
                    </table>`
    
    table.append(contenidoTabla);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 my-4" id="table"></div>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, me gusta tu idea y la implementación, lo aplicare y te aviso, mientras +1